# Linguagem Ruby - Dúvida sobre métodos

Tags: string, ruby

Tenho uma dúvida sobre a linguagem Ruby:

```
class Carro

  attr_accessor :marca, :modelo, :cor

  # declaração do método dentro da classe
  def velocidade_maxima
    250
  end
end

carro = Carro.new
puts "insira marca carro:"
carro.marca = gets
puts "insira modelo:"
carro.modelo = gets
puts "insira cor:"
carro.cor = gets
puts "a marca é " + carro.marca
puts carro.modelo
puts carro.cor
# AQUI
puts "velocidade do carro é de " + carro.velocidade_maxima
```

Gostaria de saber por que não consigo pôr `string + carro.velocidade_maxima` para exibir `250`, enquanto que os outros consigo concatenar normalmente?

Seria o método `velocidade_maxima` inacessível fora da classe? Se sim, como faço para acessar sem ser por `attr_accessor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[O erro que dá no seu código](https://ideone.com/bZe6sF) é:

> no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)

Ou seja, você está tentando concatenar um número (`250`) em uma string (`"velocidade do carro é de"`). Para resolver isso, você pode converter o número para string:

```
puts "velocidade do carro é de " + carro.velocidade_maxima.to_s
```

Ou interpolar a expressão dentro da própria string:

```
puts "velocidade do carro é de #{carro.velocidade_maxima}"
```

Veja o código rodando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/XHW4x8).

---

Nos outros atributos esse problema não acontece porque [`gets` retorna uma string](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), e por isso a concatenação ocorre sem problemas.

Comment: Valeu amigo. Também tinha esquecido a possibilidade da interpolação. No caso, gets sempre irá retornar string ou pode ser outro tipo?

Comment: @Renan Pelo que vi na [documentação](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), o retorno é uma string